# How to nest an each loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a dashboard where I need to fetch the parent menu and display the child menu under each parent menu. The problem I am facing is that I get all the parent menu first and the child menus displays last.

**HERE IS MY JQUERY CODE**

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {

  if (value.ParentId == 0) {
    //Get and display the parent Menu
    var input = ('<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' + value.Id + ' />' + "  " + value.MenuName + " (PARENT) " + '</label><br>');
    $('#appName').append(input);
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      //Fetch the children menus
      url: 'http://localhost:61768/api/users/GetUrlChildren?Id=' + value.Id,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(localStorage.getItem('AppId') + ":" + localStorage.getItem('ApiKey'))
      },
      success: function(newData) {
        $.each(newData, function(index2, value2) {
          if (Object.keys(newData).length == 0) {
            alert("No Url has been added");
          } else {
            //Display the children menu.
            var input2 = ('<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' + value2.Id + ' />' + "  " + value2.MenuName + " (CHILD) " + '</label><br>');
            $('#appName').append(input2);
          }
        });
      }
    });

  }

});
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgqyc.png]

Comment: well that is how asynchronous calls work

Comment: What do you want to happen? Have each parent wait for it's children before displaying?

Comment: That's because `$.ajax` is asynchronous. You can consider placing the `$('#appName').append(input);` line inside the success callback, before `$('#appName').append(input2);`

Comment: your outer loop isn't waiting for the ajax call (which is async, don't forget) to return before carrying on with the next iteration and generating another ajax request, plus continuing to append more data into "appName". Inevitably, this means that things happen in a less-than-predictable order. An approach based on promises, where you don't start the next request until the previous one completes, will work much better.

Comment: @arbuthnott I want the parent menu to display and then the child.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the parent node in a div and append the children to this parent div so something like:

https://jsfiddle.net/ukady6ov/

My example is in normal ES5, but `$.each` works the same way as my `forEach`. And your `$.ajax` call is simulated by my `Promise`. The trick is in the nesting of the elements.

Comment: your answer looks great which i could see it in jquery. Any chance?

Comment: Will try and create an example using jQuery later today. It should look quite similar to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that the order of appearance is *parentA, parentB, parentC, childA1, childA2, childB1, childB2,...* etc, and what you want is *parentA, childA1, childA2, parentB, ...*

There's a reasonably easy fix that will delay the appearance of the parent until all children are ready:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {

  if (value.ParentId == 0) {
    //Get and display the parent Menu
    var input = $('<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' + value.Id + ' />' + "  " + value.MenuName + " (PARENT) " + '</label><br>');
    input.css('display', 'none'); // hidden by default
    $('#appName').append(input);
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      //Fetch the children menus
      url: 'http://localhost:61768/api/users/GetUrlChildren?Id=' + value.Id,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(localStorage.getItem('AppId') + ":" + localStorage.getItem('ApiKey'))
      },
      success: function(newData) {
        $.each(newData, function(index2, value2) {
          if (Object.keys(newData).length == 0) {
            alert("No Url has been added");
          } else {
            //Display the children menu.
            var input2 = ('<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' + value2.Id + ' />' + "  " + value2.MenuName + " (CHILD) " + '</label><br>');
            $('#appName').append(input2);
          }
        });
        // now reveal the parent
        input.css('display', 'inline-block'); // or block etc if your css requires
      }
    });

  }

});
```

This will likely result in the appearance order you want. It does not guarantee that the first parent will be shown first (etc) though that would be likely.

If you want to guarantee that the parents are revealed in the order passed to the `$.each` that's a bit more complicated. But any management of this order will definitely involve imposing some sort of WAIT condition (above, I made the parent display wait for it's children) - you cannot achieve it just be reordering the `$.each` loops.